How can I do complex calculations in MYSQL?
How can I find all rows in a table of data, which are relative to the result of some calculation between data from rows in another table?
(As an example, for an eshop, I want to find all products (rows) in a table of products, which are having a price (column in another table) that is below the sum of the relative shipping price, plus the regular price of this product (that data are in another table).
How can I achieve this?
To make it more clear, lets try it with a woocommerce  MYSQL query:
SELECT * FROM eu_posts p 
 WHERE p.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM eu_postmeta m 
             WHERE m.meta_key="_regular_price" 
           AND m.meta_value < (SELECT m.meta_value 
                        WHERE m.meta_key='shipping_cost' 
                          AND m.post_id = p.ID) + 
                      (SELECT m.meta_value 
                        WHERE m.meta_key='bb_price' 
                      AND m.post_id = p.ID)); 

but the above returns an empty set, though there are rows of products with price lower than the expected sum of the two other values.
Is it possible to do such calculations inside MYSQL?

Please see: Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?.

"Yes" but I doubt that's the answer you're looking for. Referring to that query as complex is going to raise some eyebrows :). When you ran that query - what error did you get? Ask the question you want an answer to, not a meta question about whether it's possible.

I cannot make it work. It runs without end.

so run an explain and ask why it doesn't complete with that information in the question.

"I cannot make it work" because you're asking the wrong questions and answering followup questions with "I cannot make it work" instead of actual helpful information like what error messages you're getting etc.

I am not getting any error, It seems to run forever.

In general, prefer joins over correlated subqueries.

You're missing the joining condition between p and m, so you're creating a full cross-product of the entire tables. If those subqueries are supposed to be the conditions, they should be in ON, not WHERE.

It finally ended, with the following error "Gateway time-out (rejected)".

Barmar, I cannot make it work this way.
SELECT * FROM eu_posts p join eu_postmeta m  WHERE meta_key="_price" and m.meta_value < (SELECT m.meta_value from eu_postmeta ON m.post_id=p.ID WHERE meta_key='shipping_cost') + (Select m.meta_value from eu_postmeta ON post_id=p.ID WHERE meta_key='_regular_price');
returns an error.
It is very complex and I search for a way to make it work

You should join with wp_postmeta multiple times, not use correlated subqueries.
SELECT p.*, m1.meta_value AS price, m2.meta_value AS shipping_cost, m3.meta_value AS regular_price
FROM wp_posts AS p
JOIN wp_postmeta AS m1 ON p.id = m1.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta AS m2 ON p.id = m2.post_id
JOIN wp_postmeta AS m3 ON p.id = m3.post_id
WHERE m1.meta_key = '_price' AND m2.meta_key = 'shipping_cost' AND m3.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND m1.meta_value < m2.meta_value + m3.meta_value


I'm curious why m1.meta_key = '_price' etc. aren't in the join conditions

Join conditions are for the relationships between tables. Conditions on a single table should be in WHERE (except in LEFT JOIN). I probably could have put the last condition in ON, though.

Try this. We can write subqueries too.
SELECT p.* 
FROM eu_posts p
JOIN eu_postmeta m1 ON p.ID = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
JOIN eu_postmeta m2 ON p.ID = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = 'shipping_cost'
JOIN eu_postmeta m3 ON p.ID = m3.post_id AND m3.meta_key = 'bb_price'
WHERE CAST(m1.meta_value AS DECIMAL) < (CAST(m2.meta_value AS DECIMAL) + CAST(m3.meta_value AS DECIMAL));


Can you explain your answers and also how its different than Barmar's answer?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It seems I found an answer, the following query works:
SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta m WHERE m.meta_key="_regular_price" 
AND m.meta_value < 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta d 
WHERE d.meta_key='shipping_cost' AND d.post_id = m.post_id ) + 
(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta e 
WHERE e.meta_key='_price' AND e.post_id = m.post_id));

The key seems to be, as Barmar seems to suggest, to name values differently.

Please format the query readably in a code block.

But, this query has a nested sub-select, which makes it hard to maintain (and read).
